# Avoiding n queries on API list call for database-calculated model attributes

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I am cleaning up a quite messy php laravel 8 project right now.

Currently my ressource looks like this:

```
class MyModelSimpleResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'my_calculated_attribute' => MyModel::whereRaw('fk_id = ? AND model_type = "xyz"', [$this->id])->count(),
        ];
    }
}
```

My problem is that on calling the API endpoint, for every record of `MyModel` it creates a separate query to calculate `my_calculated_attribute`.

I know that you can define foreign key constrains in the model like and query like this:

```
MyModel::with('myFkModel')->get()
```

This works great for foreign keys. But how can I avoid *n* queries when I need this `my_calculated_attribute`.

Thanks a lot!

PS: I know that raw queries are a bad idea and I know that the resource is supposed to transform data and not query it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I don't only can define foreign keys in my model! I just defined a new relationship:

```
public function myFkModels(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(MyFkModel::class);
}

public function myFkWithCondition(): HasMany
{
    return $this->myFkModels()->where('model_type ', 'xyz');
}
```

This I can put in my `with` statement like this:

```
MyModel::with('myFkModels', 'myFkWithCondition')->get()
```

Comment: This kinda looks like a Polymorphic relationship (related via `id` and `type`), could you adapt [Laravel's Implementation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) to your use case?

Comment: Actually its a regular FK but I need the aggregated value per object in this singel use-case.

Comment: Makes sense! The only other thing I could offer is the `withCount()` option, which you could use as `withCount('myFkWithCondition')`, then in your resource, `'my_calculated_attribute' => $this->my_fk_with_condition_count` (i.e. you don't have to manually call `(...)->count()`). Glad you got this working regardless 

Comment: Thats really a great idea! Thx!